# Filtering based on DeviceID in PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter out drives based on DeviceID, however its failing. When I try using DriveType its working fine.

For Example:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3 ")
```

Returns:

```
DeviceID     : C:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName :
FreeSpace    : 181411000320
Size         : 255791026176
VolumeName   :
```

However if I try using DeviceID:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID = C")
```

It returns:

> (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID = C")
>   Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where
>   DeviceID
>   = C" At line:1 char:2
>   + (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID = C")
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], Management    Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C
>   ommands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'")
```

Looks like you need to use quote marks around the drive letter and include the colon.